# Event handler to run jQuery based on URL

Tags: jquery, url, event-handling

Is there a jQuery event handler that runs a script if the page has a certain URL? Similar to `$( document ).ready(function() {` but only if the page has a particular URL.

I want to run a script when the page is ready but only for a page with URL '.../something/somethingelse/'.

The view has links that redirect to new URLs to change layout aspects - but it's the same view (I'm using django web framework)

Comment: check out window.location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location` like below:-

An example:-

```js
if(window.location.href =='http://stacksnippets.net/js'){
  console.log(window.location.hostname);
  console.log(window.location.href);
}else{
  $('#getHostNameandHref').html(window.location.hostname +'----'+window.location.href);
  console.log('other page');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="getHostNameandHref"><div>
```

Note:- you can check `console.log(window.location);` to see what available options are there which you can use.Thanks

Comment: @RuthYoung  glad to help you.:):)